# How to Add an Appointment to a Shared Calendar in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am attempting to create an appointment taken from a `.CSV` file with Subject and Date and place this in someone else's shared calendar.

I have full editor's permissions for this shared calendar. By shared calendar I mean, a regular calendar made in the person's Outlook and clicking "Share" and emailing it to others.

```
Sub ImportAppointments(full_path As String)

'Initialize variables
Dim exlApp As Excel.Application
Dim exlWkb As Workbook
Dim exlSht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim itmAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

' Create reference to Excel
Set exlApp = New Excel.Application

' Select file path, currently hardcoded to one directory, change as needed
Dim strFilepath As String
'strFilepath = "P:\Holiday Calendar\Holiday_Calendar_Data.csv"
strFilepath = full_path

' Select workbook (the above .csv file) and select the first worksheet as the data sheet
Set exlSht = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strFilepath).Worksheets(1)

' Initialize variables
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim oNs As Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

' Allow accessing data stored in the user's mail stores in Outlook
Set oNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Set share calender owner
Set objOwner = oNs.CreateRecipient("calvin@xyz.ca")
    objOwner.Resolve

If objOwner.Resolved Then

    ' Set up non-default share folder location
    Set olFldr = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar).Folders("Holiday Calendar")

End If

' Start point
iRow = 2
iCol = 1

' Loop through each calendar entry
While exlSht.Cells(iRow, 1) <> ""

    Set itmAppt = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    ' Set appointment Subject, ie (Vacation, Sick Day, Half-Day, etc.)
    itmAppt.Subject = exlSht.Cells(iRow, 1)

    ' Set Date of Event
    itmAppt.Start = exlSht.Cells(iRow, 2)

    ' Force All Day Event
    itmAppt.AllDayEvent = True

    ' Save appointment
    itmAppt.Save

    ' Advance pointer to next row
    iRow = iRow + 1

    ' Transfer appointment into shared calendar folder
    itmAppt.Move olFldr

Wend

' Close everything
Excel.Application.Workbooks.Close
exlApp.Quit
Set exlApp = Nothing
Set olFldr = Nothing
Set itmAppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

My code fails to find the "Holiday Calendar" if I try to insert at someone else's calendar with

```
Set olFldr = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar).Folders("Holiday Calendar")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `Application.CreateItem` / `AppointmentItem.Move`, create the item directly using `olFldr.Items.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is slightly off if the calendar you are writing to is at the same folder level as the default calendar:

```
Set olFldr = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar).Folders("Holiday Calendar")
```

Instead, you need to specify .Parent before the .Folders property

```
Set olFldr = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("Holiday Calendar")
```

I derived this answer from: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Comment: If the shared folders are cached (which they are by default), GetSharedDefaultFolder will return the cached folder form the primary mailbox's OST store. That cached folder does not expose subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this as it took me ages to come up with a solution to add a calendar meeting request from an Exchange Shared Mailbox.

This code creates, displays and pre-fills an appointment which will be saved in the Shared Mailbox, and if sent to other recipients will appear to the recipient as being sent from the shared mailbox account!

```
Sub SendEmailFromSharedMailbox()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application

Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

  Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("Shared Mailbox Name")
    objOwner.Resolve

 If objOwner.Resolved Then
   MsgBox objOwner.Name
 Set newCalFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderCalendar)

'Now create the email
 Set olAppt = newCalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
     With olAppt
     'Define calendar item properties
        .Start = "19/9/2019 2:00 PM"
        .End = "19/9/2019 2:30 PM"
        .Subject = "Appointment Subject Here"
        .Recipients.Add ("someone@email.com")
        'Add more variables as required, eg reminder, importance, etc
        .Display
    End With
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%Folder%.items.Add` worked for me. I was trying to setup a macro to create an appointment that automatically fills in the recipients and brings up the window to make any changes before sending off.

```
Sub Travel_Calendar_Creation()

    Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As Outlook.folder
    Dim appt As Object
    Dim optAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Travel Calendar")
    Set appt = folder.items.Add
    Set optAttendee = appt.Recipients.Add("%Contact%; %Contact%; %Contact%")
    
    appt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    appt.Subject = "Traveling to: "
    appt.Start = Now()
    appt.Duration = 90
    optAttendee.Type = olOptional
    appt.Display
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Shared not default calendar.