# Importing Appointments from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a Shared Outlook Appointment calendar that's linked to a colleague's account. I am trying to export the appointments from that calendar to Excel.

I found lots of pages of VBA code showing how to export from their main calendar by using their email address in the code however this Calendar has been set up as an appointment calendar only and is separate from the user's main calendar. When I reference her email address, it pulls from her main calendar.

The Appointment Calendar was shared by email and I needed to accept to add it to my own calendar lists.

I guess I need to name this specific calendar in the code?

Comment: Thank youe Sture, yes I have Googled and I saw this code before. When I tried however it worked on my own email address but when I replaced it with my colleagues since it's trying to gain access to her Default calendar, it's not working. Is there a way I can reference the specific Shared Appointment Calendar, for example "Annual Leave Days". Everyone adds data here and others will need to use this code, and she can't give public access to her Default calendar to everyone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52525690/1571407 shows how you might navigate the other user's calendar folder structure. As well the link shows how to use your navigation pane "Access a Folder Opened from a Sharing Invitation". If you are successful you may post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you got a calendar folder you can try to get the parent folder and then iterate over all subfolders along with a shared calendar already retrieved. Hope there you will be able to find what you need.

To get a shared calendar folder you need to use the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
 Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

So, after getting the default calendar folder you may ask for the parent folder (see the `Parent` property). Then you can use the [Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.folders) property which returns the `Folders` collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified Folder. Iterating over all subfolders you mat find the required one.